# LINQ to Entity query execution time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this LINQ to Entity query which fetches around 5000 Plus records. I have been noticed is that the higher the records returned the more time it takes to execute the query and return the results.

```
 lstUserAssignments =  context.UserAssessments.Where(a=>a.UserID == UserID && a.CourseID == ClassID && a.ProductID == a.ProductID && a.AppID == ApplicationID && a.IsDeleted == false && a.Score_Percentage >= 0).Select(a=> new UserAssessmentEntity()
                                          {
                                              ApplicationID = a.AppID,
                                              AttemptNo = a.AttemptNo,
                                              CourseID = a.CourseID,
                                              Score_Percentage = (float)(a.Score_Percentage != null ? a.Score_Percentage : 0),
                                              Status = a.Status,
                                              UserAssessmentID = a.UserAssessmentID,
                                              UserID = a.UserID,
                                              UserScore = a.User_Score,
                                              CreatedDateTime = a.CreatedDateTime,
                                              ModifiedDateTime = a.ModifiedDateTime,
                                              TimeSpent=a.UserAssessmentDetails.Sum(i=>i.TimeSpent??0),
                                              InstructorFeedbackText = a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault()!=null?a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault().InstructorFeedbackText:string.Empty
                                          }).ToList();
```

To make the query simple. There is UserAssessment and UserAssessmentDetails table. The first one is the parent and the latter the child. There is some performance issue in the query and i feel its in calculating TimeSpent and InstructorFeedback. 
   Can anyone point my finger on the problem.

Comment: "There is some performance issue in the query and i feel its in calculating TimeSpent and InstructorFeedback". What have you done to check this - have you run SQL Profiler, grabbed the generated query, and executed it manually with "Show Actual Execution Plan" turned on?
Yes it could be the aggregate functions but unless you actually measure this no-one can help you to fix it...

Comment: I guess the problem being you're bringing back 5,000+ records and putting them into memory. Does someone look at those 5,000 at once?

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see what statement really gets executed. It looks like your statement first fetches the assessments and then queries for the details ONE AT A TIME

Comment: MY first port of call would be SQL query profiler to see what kind of SQL is being executed and see if that's what is taking the time.

Comment: You should optimize this line: `InstructorFeedbackText = a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault()!=null?a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault().InstructorFeedbackText:string.Empty`

Comment: `higher the records returned the more time it takes to execute the query and return the results.` you did expect a different behavior? Either way, do you really need 5000+ results at once? What are you planning to do with that amount of data?

Comment: @Alberto That line also pops as very inneficient and it might trigger a N+1 query. it should be `a.UserAssessmentDetails.Select(d => d.InstructorFeedbackText).FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty` and avoid the existence check.

Comment: What if you use Take() and Skip() ? Need pagination in your code. This will help.See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Take and Skip:
context.UserAssessments.Where(a=>a.UserID == UserID && a.CourseID == ClassID && a.ProductID == a.ProductID && a.AppID == ApplicationID && a.IsDeleted == false && a.Score_Percentage >= 0).Select(a=> new UserAssessmentEntity()
                                          {
                                              ApplicationID = a.AppID,
                                              AttemptNo = a.AttemptNo,
                                              CourseID = a.CourseID,
                                              Score_Percentage = (float)(a.Score_Percentage != null ? a.Score_Percentage : 0),
                                              Status = a.Status,
                                              UserAssessmentID = a.UserAssessmentID,
                                              UserID = a.UserID,
                                              UserScore = a.User_Score,
                                              CreatedDateTime = a.CreatedDateTime,
                                              ModifiedDateTime = a.ModifiedDateTime,
                                              TimeSpent=a.UserAssessmentDetails.Sum(i=>i.TimeSpent??0),
                                              InstructorFeedbackText = a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault()!=null?a.UserAssessmentDetails.FirstOrDefault().InstructorFeedbackText:string.Empty
                                          }).Take(10).Skip(10).ToList();
```

Comment: I need all the records returned since i would be used for processing and report generation